# Cannot get PHP Mail() function to work

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04, php

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed PHP5, Apache2. Then I used following php code to send a mail.

```
 <?php
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "mymail@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "Mail Sent.";
}  else {
    echo 'failed';
}

?>
```

I installed sendmail using apt-get install sendmail and ran above code. And it displays "Mail Sent", but there is no any mail in my inbox. I tried hard to figure the issue but I couldn't. Please help me to send a mail using PHP mail() function.

**Edited:** I tried with postfix by 'sudo apt-get install postfix'. Then also it displays "Mail Sent", but there is no mails in my inbox.

Thank you..!!

Comment: Since you have not set the headers, you should check your spam folder

Comment: Yup that should be in spam... If that didn't work,try gmail smtp

Comment: gmail smtp SSL having some issue since last few days so use TSL

Comment: I checked my spam.. but there is no any mails in it..Now I am trying to create smtp server

Comment: What did you try? Have you tried sending an email from the command line? What's happenning to mailq? What dose the mail log show?

Comment: yes..I tried with command line..mail log give message like     "Dec  5 18:27:53 visitha-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC postfix/postdrop[19158]: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory". And mailq displays "postqueue: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a SMTP server running to send email.

In php.ini, try changing these lines:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25 
; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = me@localhost.com
```

or start a SMTP server on `localhost`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I changed above lines in etc/php5/apache2/php.ini but it didn't work. Can you give me some guidance to start a SMTP server on localhost? I really appreciate it.